# Objective-C: Find and Replace in String

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsmutablestring

I have a string, dynamically generated from a website, that I would like to change.

I already know you need to change the string to a `NSMutableString`, but the part I want to remove is almost never the same. (e.g. `[XXXXX]` or `[XABXX]` ... there are thousands of combos).

The only static parts are the square brackets on either end and that there are 5 characters in between.

How would I recognise and remove this string of seven characters (`[*****]`, with the *'s representing a random letter)?

Comment: maybe with regular expression...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using the [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to find each substring you need to operate on.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with regexes, except for `NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\["` (... replace with "") If I do this, I get a blank output. Any other regex is fine. Is there a way that you know works to remove a "["?

Comment: `\[` is the correct escape sequence. Did you use `\[\d{5}\]` ?

Comment: I get unknown escape sequence for `\d` and `\]`

Comment: nevermind. Just note that in obj-c, you need to escape like this: `\\[`

Answer (score 3):

A simple search and you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217484/need-to-remove-string-which-in-between-the-braces):

with a simple change:

```
- (NSString *)stringCleaner:(NSString *)yourString {
    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"[" intoString:NULL] ;
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"]" intoString:&text] ;
        yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@]", text] withString:@""];
    }

    return yourString;
}
```

Comment: can you put this in an IBAction?

Comment: sure, you can set a IBAction method with that code but instead of returning the string will just set the value where you need it or just do this:


//add this action to UIButton
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
 NSString *finalString = [self stringCleaner:@"mytext[azert]toReplace"];

//do something with finalString
}